# Bootstrap dynamically change panel-body content

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, panel

I have to work on a webpage using HTML, CSS, JS and Bootstrap. Thing is I'm pretty much discovering/rediscovering all of them, and despite my search I couldn't find any answer.

So simple question: is it possible to change a bootstrap panel-body's content by clicking a button via a JavaScript or something?

By default the panel-body displays a form to fill. Under it is another panel-body displaying a table of the received forms with buttons to display more informations, and when I click that button I want to replace the form of the first panel-body with a table of said informations.

Comment: You can use inner html, append, or display to set content dynamically any where not only panel-body.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, just take a look at `display` options using JavaScript -to show or hide content- and just get values from form to set them in the table body -to move data from one place to other-.

If you show us the code we would help you.